# What's the proper way to generate log while conducting git command in batch-file

Tags: git, batch-file, command-line, pipe, stdout

I'm implementing log feature to a TFS git automatically backup batch.

The Batch is like

```
@echo on

set source=https://url.src/
set dest=http://url.dest/

cd \gitrepo

for /f %%r in (distributiontools.txt) do (
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r
cd %%r.git
git push --all %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r
git push --tags %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r
cd \gitrepo
rd /q/s %%r.git
)
```

I tried syntax like

```
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/ProjectName &> log.txt
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/ProjectName 2>&1 &> log.txt
```

But the cmd window disappeared right after clicked and left nothing. And

```
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/ProjectName >> log.txt
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/ProjectName > log.txt
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/ProjectName 2>&1 >> log.txt
```

It processed correctly but log.txt was blank.

I end up doing,

Batch1

```
@echo on

set source=https://url.src/
set dest=http://url.dest/

cd \gitrepo

for /f %%r in (distributiontools.txt) do (
git clone --mirror %source%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r 2>&1
cd %%r.git
git push --all %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r 2>&1
git push --tags %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r 2>&1
cd \gitrepo
rd /q/s %%r.git
)
```

Batch2

```
Batch1 >> log.txt
```

And triggered the process from Batch2.

I feel there should be an easier way to achieve the same but I'm not familiar with the batch syntax that I can't figure out how.

Comment: The output from `git push` is sent over STDERR, `2>`, but is not human readable. In order to read it, you'd need to convert it using the `--porcelain` option, which should also send it to STDOUT, `1>`. I would suggest you try, `git push --all --porcelain %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r > log.txt` and `git push --tags --porcelain %dest%Distribution%%20Tools/_git/%%r >> log.txt`.

Comment: I tried above, the log.txt is blank as well. Does it only output when the encountering error?